How much time per day do international concertists typically spend on the *exercices* part only
How much time per day do international concertists typically spend on the exercices part only (so not counting pieces, and not counting exercices dedicated to a specific piece) : so counting only "academic general exercices": arpeggio, scale, etc.

That question isn't an exact duplicate, as it doesn't ask for an exact time duration, but it's very similar in spirit and I feel like its answers might be helpful to you. I also agree with @user1079505 that a more useful question might be "How long should I spend," though it would still be hard to answer (depends on how much time you have available, what you're working on, etc.), and is better asked of a teacher than strangers on the internet.

Perhaps my original comment was overly sarcastic, I agree with how @AndyBonner formulated it.

There can be no concrete answer to this question. It will vary considerably from performer to performer.
However, most will probably spend a short time warming up, by playing scales, arpeggios, favourite snippets. Let's face it, there's not a lot to warm up for a pianist. It also may depend on the sort of piece they're going to subsequently practise - one with a lot of stretches will most likely incur stretching exercises, for example.

This is just a guess based on little to no concrete information. Among other things, some pianists find a great deal of warm-up is required.

The question is asking for a rough quantitative estimation of typical case.

I wrote explicitely "not counting exercices dedicated to a specific piece"

Despite the dvs, I stand by this answer. There is no typical spent time, just like there is no typical performer. Basically, I should not have proffered an answer to an unanswerable question. How would one find out? In fairness, the dv on the question is mine.

@Tim To answer the question would require a survey of pianists' practice habits, including reviewing books, interviews, essays, youtube videos, etc. And that answer could still change over time. However, the main problem with the question is that it is "likely to be answered with opinions", which is the close criterion.

@Aaron - I'd vtc on the phrase containing 'typical', but that's not really an option - is it?

I didn’t dv but this assertion seems very hard to defend: "there's not a lot to warm up for a pianist". Piano is a whole body instrument, just like all of them are.
